# How to set Session to ReceiveInvoice in Combobox to hold the Receive_ID for very next Entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I want to use receive invoice  for very next entry using session but it don't. Here I populate Receive InvoiceNo in create controller. please help me..

```
  var rmaster = db.FactoryReceiveMaster.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> lstFactoryReceiveMaster = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (rmaster != null && rmaster.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var rInvoice in rmaster)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new  SelectListItem { Text = rInvoice.RInvoiceNo, Value = rInvoice.Receive_ID.ToString(), Selected = false };
                lstFactoryReceiveMaster.Add(item);
            }

        }
        Session["lstFactoryReceiveMaster"] = lstFactoryReceiveMaster;
        model.AssembleInvoice = lstFactoryReceiveMaster;
```

Create View....

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@model MvcMahindraTwoWheelerERP.Models.FactoryProductAssembledViewModel 

 <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 style="font-family:cursive;font-size:large;"> Assemble Product - Entry Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FactoryAssembleProduct", FormMethod.Post))            
        {      
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
              <div class="form-horizontal"> 
                  <div class="form-group">   
                                <div class="form-group">                                  
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
                                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assembled_Date)
                                  @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.Assembled_Date).Format("dd/MMM/yyyy").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:100%;"}))                                                
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Assembled_Date)  
                                </div>
                                </div>

                               <div class="form-group">                                  
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
                                 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FactoryReceiveMaster.RInvoiceNo)                          
                                 @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.FactoryReceiveMaster.Receive_ID).BindTo(Model.AssembleInvoice).HtmlAttributes(new {@style = "width:100%;"}))                                               
                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FactoryReceiveMaster.Receive_ID)    
                                </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">                                  
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ProdCode)                          
                                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Product.ProductID).BindTo(Model.AssembleProducts).HtmlAttributes(new {id="ProductID", @style = "width:100%;"}).Filter(FilterType.Contains))                                               
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ProductID)  
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">                                   
                                 <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4"> 
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { id="descriptipn", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">                                   
                                 <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4"> 
                                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chassis_No)
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Chassis_No, new {@class = "form-control" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chassis_No) 
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">                                    
                                 <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">  
                                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Engine_No)                                 
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Engine_No, new {@class = "form-control" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Engine_No)
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">                                     
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">   
                                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Key_No)                                  
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Key_No, new {@class = "form-control" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Key_No) 
                                </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">                                  
                                 <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
                                  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks)                                   
                                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Remarks, new {@class = "form-control" })
                                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Remarks) 
                                </div>
                                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Save Changes" />
                    </div>
                </div>

          </div>  
      </div>             
        }
  </div>
```

Now, now how to fix it ...?